# Why we can use methods of ArrayList without creating new ArrayList object?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

We have to create a object of any class to use their funtionalities unless those are static functionalities. But why we dont need to create a ArrayList object to use its methods like add, contains etc..

```
ArrayList<Egg> myList = new ArrayList<Egg>();
myList.add(a);
```

According to my understanding, myList is just variable which holds ArrayList object's reference of type ArrayList class. So again how can we write following without passing object to myList.

```
ArrayList<Egg> myList;
myList.add(a);
```

Complete code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DotCom {
    private ArrayList<String> locationCells;

    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc)
    {
        locationCells = loc;
    }

    public String checkYourself(String userInput)
    {
        String result = "miss";
        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);
        if (index >= 0) {
            locationCells.remove(index);
            if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
                result = "kill";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "hit";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //TODO:  all the following code was added and should have been included in the book
    private String name;
    public void setName(String string) {
        name = string;
    }
}
```

PS
I am referring heads first java book.

Comment: You're not giving near enough code to let the question be answerable. How is myList being assigned a reference, for instance?

Comment: You do need to create an instance; that will not work.

Comment: And your 2nd code may compile, but will throw a NullPointerException if you try to run it

Comment: "So again how can we write following" - well you can _write_ a lot of things and depending on the editor/ide you might not see any error. The compiler or at least the runtime would complain about that though.

Comment: But right now, all we can do is guess because you've not yet posted a complete small program, a [mre], that illustrates the point you're trying to make.

Comment: Is `myList` a field or a local variable?

Comment: OK, so now you see your answer -- the ArrayList reference needs to be set with the setter method that the class has: `public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc)`. There's no magic going on here, no uninitialized variables being used (unless you try to refer to the ArrayList before setting the reference, and then you'll get the NullPointerException).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArrayList reference is being set in the setter method:

```
public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc)
{
    locationCells = loc;
}
```

If this method is not called, and the reference not set before trying to use the ArrayList, then the code will throw a NullPointerException.

Side note: This does not look to be safe code, since it *can* be easily run incorrectly and so a NPE is easy to create. Better perhaps to set the ArrayList (List is even better) in a constructor.

Comment: @Dexter: it's exactly what the method parameter *says* that it is, no?

Comment: Okay got it!! Thank you.

Comment: @Dexter: more importantly, in the future, please strive to ask more complete questions. If we don't have to extract the key information from you, the process goes much smoother. Please read the [ask] for site best-practices when asking.

Comment: I will take my time when composing a question next time. Thank you for the suggestion.